# Windows Phone emulator won't start with a "Another Virtual Machine Manager is running." error

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express for Windows Phone (with SDK 7.1.1 update) and I'm trying to debug but when the emulator tries to launch, it gives me this error:

> Another Virtual Machine Manager is running. Close the other Virtual
>   Machine Manager, wait for some duration, and relaunch the Emulator.

Anybody know what's going on? I'm running this on a physical machine (not on a VM)

Comment: Did you try to restart your computer?

Comment: Are you running anything in Windows XP Mode at the same time?

Comment: No, I'm not running anything in XP mode

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Intel (R) Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM). that's installed with the latest Android SDK?

If you have installed this component is the Windows Phone 7 emulator will spit out that error, to resolve it you have to uninstall it and reboot.

Comment: I have that installed but I've had it installed for a while and my emulator was running then.

Comment: alright well that's what happened to me when I had both installed, what version of windows are you running?  You could always try uninstalling HAXM to see if it fixes it, if it doesn't you just re-install it no harm done.